# After updatateing my eclipse getting this error constantly for egit

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, egit

An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
org/eclipse/egit/core/project/RepositoryMapping

An internal error occurred during: "Git Repository Change Scanner".
org/eclipse/egit/core/RepositoryCache

The selected wizard could not be started.
Plug-in "org.eclipse.egit.ui" was unable to instantiate class "org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.clone.GitImportWizard".
org/eclipse/egit/core/op/CloneOperation$PostCloneTask

I have tried adding plugins again but still not able to solve problem

Comment: Please go to the _Error Log_ view, select the error (do not open it, just select it), hit Ctrl+C and paste it into your question formatted as _Sample Code_.

Comment: What version were you on before and after the update? Was eGit updated as well?